# Oracle 'Invalid Identifier' in sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having an issue with converting a view from PostgreSQL to Oracle when a sub-query is referencing a column in the outer query.

This issue seems to have been discussed here several times but I have been unable to get any of the fixes to work with my specific query.

The query's purpose is to get a mobile devices last recorded position and get the distance in KM from it's closest checkpoint/Geo-boundary and it references 3 separate tables: devices, device_locations and checkpoints.

```
SELECT 
    d.id,
    dl.latitude AS last_latitude,
    dl.longitude AS last_longitude,
    (SELECT * /* Get closest 'checkpoint' to the last device position by calculating the Great-circle distance */
    FROM (
        SELECT
            6371 * acos(cos(dl.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) * cos(checkpoints.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) * cos((checkpoints.longitude / (180/acos(-1))) - (dl.longitude / (180/acos(-1)))) + sin(dl.latitude  / (180/acos(-1))) * sin(checkpoints.latitude / (180/acos(-1)))) AS distance
        FROM checkpoints
        ORDER BY distance)
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS distance_to_checkpoint
FROM devices d
LEFT JOIN ( /* Get the last position of the device */
    SELECT l.id,
        l.time,
        l.latitude,
        l.longitude,
        l.accuracy
    FROM device_locations l
    WHERE l.ROWID IN (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM device_locations GROUP BY id) 
    ORDER BY l.id, l.time DESC) dl 
ON dl.id = d.id;
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and hoping someone can put me on the right path, thanks.

Comment: You have an extra comma here `AS distance_to_checkpoint,`

Comment: The query doesn't get the last device positions. It gets the records with the highest `ROWID` per `ID` which may happen to be the latest entry, but is not at all guaranteed to be. How would you actually determine which position is last? By the `time` column? And in spite of its name the `ID` in `device_locations` is not the table's ID? It's the device ID instead? You should definitly change that name. The `ORDER BY` clause in that subquery is completely superfluous by the way.

Comment: Which Oracle Version are you using?

Comment: And you want to see all device IDs, even those that don't have a `device_locations` record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a follow-up to my other answer. In order to get the `checkpoints` record with the minimum distance, you'd join with the table and use window functions again to pick the best record. E.g.:

```
select
  device_id,
  last_latitude,
  last_longitude,
  checkpoint_latitude,
  checkpoint_longitude,
  distance
from
(
  select
    device_id,
    last_latitude,
    last_longitude,
    checkpoint_latitude,
    checkpoint_longitude,
    distance,
    min(distance) over (partition by device_id) as min_distance
  from
  (
    select
      d.id as device_id,
      dl.latitude as last_latitude,
      dl.longitude as last_longitude,
      cp.latitude as checkpoint_latitude,
      cp.longitude as checkpoint_longitude,
      6371 *
      acos(cos(dl.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) *
           cos(cp.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) *
           cos((cp.longitude / (180/acos(-1))) - (dl.longitude / (180/acos(-1))))
           + 
           sin(dl.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) *
           sin(cp.latitude / (180/acos(-1)))
          ) as distance
    from devices d
    left join 
    (
      select 
        id as device_id, latitude, longitude, time,
        max(time) over (partition by id) as max_time
      from device_locations
    ) dl on dl.device_id = d.id and dl.time = dl.max_time
    cross join checkpoints cp
  )
)
where (distance = min_distance) or (distance is null and min_distance is null);
```

Such queries are easier to write with `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`, available as of Oracle 12c.

Comment: This solved my issue and I learnt a few things, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

1. Extra comma after you final select column: `AS distance_to_checkpoint,`
2. Outer select columns reference an inner table `device_locations l`, instead of the derived table `dl` - example: `l.latitude` should be `dl.latitude`

Comment: Thanks I've fixed those issues, but there is still an invalid identifier in the great-circle distance subquery:

ORA-00904: "DL"."LATITUDE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 192

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The query doesn't get the last device positions. It gets the records with the highest `ROWID` per `ID` which may happen to be the latest entry, but is not at all guaranteed to be.

Then you most probably have an issue with scope. Unfortunately, names are only valid one level deep, which is an annoying limitation. `dl.latitude` etc. are probably not valid in your subquery, because it's actually a subquery within a subquery. Anyway, what you are trying to get is the minimum distance, which you can easily get with `MIN`.

An `ORDER BY` in a subquery is superfluous in standard SQL. Oracle makes an exception for their `ROWNUM` technique, but I wouldn't make use of this. (And as mentioned, it's even clumsy for getting a minimum value.) The `ORDER BY` in the outer join is superfluous anyway.

This is how I would approach the problem:

```
select
  d.id as device_id,
  dl.latitude as last_latitude,
  dl.longitude as last_longitude,
  (
    select min(6371 *
               acos(cos(dl.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) *
                    cos(cp.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) *
                    cos((cp.longitude / (180/acos(-1))) - (dl.longitude / (180/acos(-1))))
                    + 
                    sin(dl.latitude / (180/acos(-1))) *
                    sin(cp.latitude / (180/acos(-1)))
                   )
               )
    from checkpoints cp
  ) as distance
from devices d
left join 
(
  select 
    id as device_id, latitude, longitude, time,
    max(time) over (partition by id) as max_time
  from device_locations
) dl on dl.device_id = d.id and dl.time = dl.max_time;
```

Comment: This seems to have solved my issue, so thank you very much for all your assistance. I do have a query though, how would I go about getting the latitude or longitude of the closest checkpoint? I haven't been able to come up with a way of doing it without running into scope issues again.